# Mule ESB CE and web application

Tags: mule, esb

How to make my mule application as an web application which i can visualize on my browser, so that the user can view the progress of each spot that means how to model my application. I'm using mule 3.5.0 CE.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is very broad.  What have you tried, and what specific problems are you encountering?

Comment: I ask the feasibility of what I think to do. Now I create a small application that takes the response of a web service that sends a push. if the push is not arrived an email is sent to this device. I deployed the application on mule standalone 3.5.0. what I want to do is a kind of web page on which an admin connects and sees for example the number of push sent. is what possible with mule ESB? if so how can I add the web page. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create web application and deploy it on Mule using jetty server.
Please have a look in it's documentation you will get plenty of example in net of accessing web application in Mule :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Jetty+Transport+Reference

and [Can Mule run a JavaEE web-application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439944/can-mule-run-a-javaee-web-application) and 
[Configured jetty server in mule esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844632/configured-jetty-server-in-mule-esb)

Also since you are using Mule 3.5.0 CE you need to use Jetty 8 as given here :- [Jetty in Mule only works in earlier version of Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892731/jetty-in-mule-only-works-in-earlier-version-of-studio)